# React child component doesn't update after props change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-select

I have a strange problem with rendering some child component after props change.I am using **CreatableInput** component from **react-select**.If you would like to look at it , you can find it here, also a source code `[react-select](https://react-select.com/creatable)
The lib itself uses internal state to manipulate it input values , but in my project i need to work with redux store.In **handleKeyDown** i take the values from internal state and send it to my redux store , after that the parent component which is connected to store, receives the changes , but it couldn't manage to update its child component. When i write something on input field and hit **ENTER or TAB** , it actually change the store , but doesn't show the value immediately , it only shows after some **blur**. It works pretty well with internal state , but not with external one .

```
import React from 'react';
import CreatableSelect from 'react-select/lib/Creatable';
import * as fp from 'lodash/fp';

const components = {
    DropdownIndicator: null,
};

const createOption = label => ({
    label,
    value: label,
});

export default class CreatableInputOnly extends React.Component {
    state = {
        inputValue: '',
        value: {
            include: [],
            exclude: [],
        },
    };

    handleChange = leftValues => {
        this.props.clearInputValues({values: leftValues, filterType: this.props.filterType});

        this.setState({
            value: {
                include: fp.cond([
                    [fp.isEqual('include'), fp.constant(leftValues)],
                    [fp.stubTrue, fp.constant([...this.state.value.include])],
                ])(this.props.filterType),
                exclude: fp.cond([
                    [fp.isEqual('exclude'), fp.constant(leftValues)],
                    [fp.stubTrue, fp.constant([...this.state.value.exclude])],
                ])(this.props.filterType),
            },
        });

    };
    handleInputChange = inputValue => {
        this.setState({inputValue});
    };
    handleKeyDown = event => {
        const {inputValue, value} = this.state;
        const addValueToStore = this.props.addValueToStore;
        const filterType = this.props.filterType;

        if (!inputValue) return;
        switch (event.key) {
        case 'Enter':
        case 'Tab':
            this.setState({
                inputValue: '',

            }, () => {
                addValueToStore({values: createOption(inputValue), filterType});
            });

            event.preventDefault();
        }
    };
    render() {
        // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-const
        let {inputValue} = this.state;
        const {isMulti, isClearable, menuIsOpen, className, classNamePrefix, filterType, inputValues} = this.props;
        const allValues = fp.cond([
            [fp.isEqual('include'), fp.constant(inputValues.includeUrls)],
            [fp.isEqual('exclude'), fp.constant(inputValues.excludeUrls)],
            [fp.stubTrue, fp.constant([])],
        ])(filterType);
        console.log(inputValues.includeUrls, '<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>');

        return (
            <CreatableSelect
                components={components}
                inputValue={inputValue}
                isClearable={isClearable}
                isMulti={isMulti}
                menuIsOpen={menuIsOpen}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
                onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
                placeholder=""
                value={allValues}
                className={className}
                classNamePrefix={classNamePrefix}
            />
        );
    }
}
```